# Nextjs13 combine server side component and client side component

Tags: next.js13

I have a scenario that fields on the page are rendered by locale and corresponding field label are fetched from server side.Whether there is a way to implement this?

General idea is that the page looks like below, this code should be done on server side since variable `usernameEn`  and `usernameFr` are retrieved from server.

In the meanwhile, the page has useState hook which indicates the page is client side component. I would like the values fetched from server before the page is rendered.

```html
'use client'
const [user, setUser] = useState({})
return (
  <div>
    <label>{locale === 'en' ? usernameEn : usernameFr}</label>
  </div>
)
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep component client-side rendered import it in page & page will be server side rendered.

Here's a example code I made,

- My server-side page calls API, passes data to client component.
- I have made a client component(User.js), which gets data as prop from server-side rendered page.
- Client component has `'use client'` on top that means it will render on client side.

*Please read this :*

- **Rendering** : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering
- **Server Components** : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components
- **Client Components** : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components
- **Server and Client Composition Patterns** : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns

**Here is code :**

**Folder Structure :**

```
projectName
├── .gitignore
├── jsconfig.json
├── next.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── next.svg
│   └── vercel.svg
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── app
│       ├── api
│       ├── comp
│       │   └── User.js
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── globals.css
│       ├── layout.js
│       ├── page.js
│       └── user
│           └── page.js
└── tailwind.config.js
```

**page.js**

```
import User from "../comp/User";

async function GetUserData() {
    let data = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/users')
    let UserData = await data.json()
    return UserData
}

// ABOVE API SIMULATES SERVER-SIDE DATA FETCHING

export default async function Page() {


    let UserData = await GetUserData();
    // STORING DATA FROM API 

    console.log("Data from API on Serverside : ", Object.keys(UserData));
    // THIS LOG WILL BE IN TERMINAL AS THIS PAGE IS SERVER-SIDE RENDERED

    // console.log("Products on Serverside :", UserData.users);
    // SHOWS USERS

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Users Page (Serverside Fetching)</h1>
            <User
                Data=
                {
                    {
                        usernameEn: UserData.users[0]['firstName'] + " ENG Locale",
                        usernameFr: UserData.users[1]['firstName'] + " FR Locale"
                    }
                }
            />

            {/* 

                HERE I AM PASSING 
                
                1ST ELEMENT'S NAME AS ENGLISH VALUE

                & 
                
                2ND ELEMENT AS Fr VALUE 

            */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**User Component :** `loc\src\app\comp\User.js` import this in page.js

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'

const User = ({ Data }) => {

    let locale = 'en'
    console.log("Data", Data);
    // IN BROWSER

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Client Component Gets data from props.</h1>
            <label>{locale === 'en' ? Data.usernameEn : Data.usernameFr}</label>
        </div>
    )
}

export default User;
```

**Output :**

- Goto `http://localhost:3000/user`
- In browser open console, you will see

`Data {usernameEn: 'Terry ENG Locale', usernameFr: 'Sheldon FR Locale'}`

- Open `Network tab`, click on user & on right hand side click on `Preview` you will see pre-rendered page.